# Override child class property using material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

This is my first question here so I hope to explain it correctly.

I have imported a datepicker element and im trying to override a class property by doing the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    testingWidthLimit: {
      width: '180px !important',
      minWidth: '180px !important',
      maxWidth: '180px !important',
    },
};

const { testingWidthLimit } = useStyles();

<InputDate
  className={testingWidthLimit}
  {other properties here}
/>
```

I cannot post a picture due to my starter reputation, but this is what's rendered on the screen:

```
<div class="sc-gXZlrW ikzFYF makeStyles-testingWidthLimit-3">
  <div class="react-date-picker react-date-picker--closed react-date-picker--enabled">
    <div class="react-date-picker__wrapper">
      (the rest goes here but that is not important)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

oh the class `"react-date-picker__wrapper"` the property `"min-width: 264px"` is still there

As you can see, I've tried every property I know of and still won't override the child property. I do not have access to the InputDate code and I have to use it.

I tried using !important (with or without space as I've seen on some other questions) and one property at a time and that is still not working, can anyone tell me what am I missing?

Edit1: on the first div, my class is being applied and all of the properties are there with the !important tag.

Comment: If you inspect that element are the styles being applied to that class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS child selector in material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54073151/css-child-selector-in-material-ui)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the syntax you need to override the `min-width` of the `react-date-picker__wrapper` descendant of the element with the `testingWidthLimit` CSS class:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    testingWidthLimit: {
      "& .react-date-picker__wrapper": {
        minWidth: 180,
      }
    },
};
```

If you need to set `min-width` on the descendant and on the `testingWidthLimit` element itself, then you would want the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    testingWidthLimit: {
      minWidth: 180,
      "& .react-date-picker__wrapper": {
        minWidth: 180,
      }
    },
};
```

Related documentation:

- https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested?v=v10.5.0#use--to-reference-selector-of-the-parent-rule
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator

Comment: Thank you very much, I was able to solve my problem using "minWidth: 180px !important" on your solution.